# What does the elif statement need to be changed to in this binary search function?

Tags: python, if-statement, binary-search

I am writing a binary search function that finds the minimum times that a given numeric list has been rotated. I believe my code is correct except for my elif statement. What needs to be changed in this code to make it work?

```
def count_rotations_binary(nums):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(nums)-1
    
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        mid_number = nums[mid]
        
        # Uncomment the next line for logging the values and fixing errors.
        print("lo:", lo, ", hi:", hi, ", mid:", mid, ", mid_number:", mid_number)
        
        if mid > 0 and mid_number < nums[mid-1]:
            # The middle position is the answer
            return mid
        
        elif mid_number > nums[mid-1]:
            # Answer lies in the left half
            hi = mid - 1  
        
        else:
            # Answer lies in the right half
            lo = mid + 1
    
    return
```

Comment: If this code isn't working the way you want, please explain.  What is it doing, and how is that different from what you wanted?

Comment: What is some sample input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: No idea what the code is supposed to do since you do not give a proper description. However, it looks like `mid_number < nums[mid-1]` should be `mid_number == nums[mid-1]` so the `else` handles the case where the pivot is smaller than the number at its left, thus making the function go to the right half of the array.

Comment: You have your middle-position and right-half cases reversed.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Input:
{'nums': [19, 25, 29, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14]} Expected Output: 3                                 lo: 0 , hi: 9 , mid: 4 , mid_number: 5
lo: 0 , hi: 3 , mid: 1 , mid_number: 25
lo: 0 , hi: 0 , mid: 0 , mid_number: 19

Actual Output:
0

Comment: @JohnGordon I am trying to count the minimum number of times an inputed list is rotated. For example: {'nums': [19, 25, 29, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14]} Expected Output: 3. My code is using the last resort which is return 0, in which a list would be in the correct order. However, my test case has been rotated and is not in order.

Comment: @JuanR I was thinking that `mid_number < nums[mid-1]` would stand for; if the mid number was smaller than the position before it, than it would return mid to be the answer for how many times the list has been rotated. It wouldn't be possible that the mid number is smaller than the one before it and the mid number not to be the answer since the rotations would be in ascending order as well. For example: Input: {'nums': [19, 25, 29, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14]} Expected Output: 3

Comment: @chepner can you explain? For example: {'nums': [19, 25, 29, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14]} Expected Output: 3.